# show data for the event which is being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could not figure it out. . When I click on particular event with unique id I need to get name of that ID but currently I a getting same name for all the ID'S clicked. Please see the below comments for the description

```js
function update(){
//this is the array of database values
dbvalues = dbvalues.split("~"); //dbvalues[i+0], dbvalues[i+1]....


//I have a label which have values form database
var  dblabel = '<br/><label class="addevents" id="' + dbvalues[i+3] + '">'+dbvalues[i+2]+ " " + dbvalues[i+4] +'</label>';

//this variable holds all the event name that are in database.
var g =dbvalues[i+2];//eg: meeting, lunch, dinner

//now this is the the real function, I am getting ID of the label, when I click  on particular ID it needs to show name of that particular ID, but currently whichever event I click it shows same name for all the IDS.
var el = document.getElementById((dbvalues[i+3]));
    
el.onclick = function () {
     alert(g); //it is showing same name for all the ID'S clicked. 
};

};
```

Comment: Where is your i variable defined?  It would normally be defined in a loop, but it seems like it's never being incremented or defined anywhere.

Comment: I have a for loop  for(i=0; i < (dbvalues.length-1);i+=5){----}, I was thinking if this function (el.onclick = function (alert(g))) has anything to do with accessing variable.

Answer (score 1):

You Can't Use Var g value Using This Way Because All The Time Var g Value Can Be Changed.
So When You Click On Element The Element At That Time Only Last Added Value Available For All var g So You Can Get Same Value For All  The Element.
At That Time If You Want To Do this You Can try Use **Html data attr** like this

```
var  dblabel = '<br/><label data-id= '+dbvalues[i+2]+' class="addevents" id="' + dbvalues[i+3] + '">'+dbvalues[i+2]+ " " + dbvalues[i+4] +'</label>';
```

And Your on Click Code Look Like This

```
el.onclick = function () {
 alert($(this).attr("data-id"));}
```

Comment: Why so many capital letters? Your answer is not a newspaper headline...

Comment: Yes you can do that as data-id. You can also add custom attr like data-name,data-name,data-url.